# Getting the error AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'timedelta' when trying to add some datetimes

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp, timedelta

I want to get the total of times by doing this inner for loop...However it seems like I am doing something wrong here, because I am getting the error AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'timedelta'...

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
N = int(input())
lista = []
for n in range(N):
    name = input()
    times = [datetime.strptime(m, '%S.%f') for m in input().split()]
    initialTime = datetime(1900,1,1,0,0,0)
    for m in times:
        initialTime += initialTime.timedelta(m)
    lista.append(initialTime)
print(lista)
```

I am also giving you some sample data:

```
5
Guilherme
20.252 20.654 20.602
Edison
24.000 24.024 23.982
Caetano
20.380 25.816 21.739
Geraldo
20.310 25.725 21.664
Luis
20.289 25.699 21.643
```

Which is intended to display the following result

```
["1:01.508", "1:12.006", "1:07.935", "1:07.699", "1:07.631"]
```

Comment: It's not clear what the line `initialTime.timedelta(m)` is supposed to be doing, as there's no assigning happening. `timedelta` is a class, it's not a method of a `datetime` object: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects Maybe your confusion is that the object is located at `datetime.timedelta`. That doesn't mean it's a property of a `datetime.datetime` object, that means it's a class in the `datetime` library. If you want to continuously increment `initialTime`, then you'd have to do `initialTime += (m - initialTime)`, assuming `m` is sooner than `initialTime`.

Comment: Hello, @RandomDavis, I have done some editting hopefully now it will make some sense for you

Comment: I edited my comment to point out the errors that I see. A `timedelta` object can either be instantiated outright, or created by subtracting two dates.

Comment: Ok, @RandomDavis, I got what you mean... Is there any workaround for what I am trying to do?

Comment: Yes there is. Please read my comment, I edited it again to suggest a workaround.

Comment: However what is the point of adding the difference between `m` and `initialTime` to `initialTime`? That would just create a date object identical to `m`, wouldn't it? It seems like `lista` and `times` would contain identical items. Unless my thinking is just way wrong.

Comment: I just want to sum up the seconds and miliseconds bellow each name, which is being read

Comment: Okay, hopefully now that you have been given the resources to know how to use `timedelta` correctly, you should be able to figure the rest out. If you can't then let us know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you are trying to add up three "lap" times to get a total time for each entry. For that, you don't need `initialTime` at all. You can convert all the time entries to `timedelta` objects and use `sum()` to add them up.

Inside your outer loop:

```
times = input().split()
for i in range(len(times)):
    t = datetime.strptime(times[i], '%S.%f')
    times[i] = timedelta(minutes=t.minute, seconds=t.second, microseconds=t.microsecond)
lista.append(sum(times, timedelta()))
```

The output will be a list of `timedelta` objects. They can be easily converted to strings with `str()` if needed.